# ssl3 alert certificate unknown on Android studio to mosquitto broker

Tags: android, ssl, mqtt

First of all, sorry i'm not good English. and it's my first question.

I'm trying to connect android and Mosquitto-broker in windows
with self-signed-certificate.
I succeeded connect mosquitto-broker and mosquitto_pub with my self-signed-certificate( `ca.crt`, `server.key`, `server.crt`, `client.key`, `client.crt` )

broker config file :

```
port 8883
cafile : ~~~/ca.crt.pem
keyfile : ~~~/server.key.pem
certfile : ~~~/server.crt.pem
tls_version tlsv1.2
require_certificate true
```

publish command :

```
mosquitto_pub -h ~~ -p ~~ -t ~~ -m ~~ --cafile ~~/ca.crt.pem --key 
~~/client.key.pem --cert ~~/client.crt.pem
```

--> it works well

```
mosquitto_pub -h ~~ -p ~~ -t ~~ -m ~~ --cafile ~~/ca.crt.pem
```

--> it not works. i don't know why it doesn't work.

but, the important thing is i can't connect to android.

I've searched, android use `.bks` file to tls/ssl. so i tried to make `.bks` file with my files on above.

The order in which I created the file is `.p12` -> `.jks` -> `.bks`

and these command :

```
.p12 : > openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt.pem -inkey client.key.pem -out client.p12 -certfile ca.crt.pem
```

```
.jks : > keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass 123123 -destkeystore client.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass 123123
```

```
.bks : > keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass 123123 -destkeystore client.bks -deststoretype BKS-v1 -deststorepass 123123 -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar
```

my android code is

```
....
mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this, "ssl://" + ipAdd.getText().toString() + ":" + port.getText().toString(), ClientID);
            try {
                /**/
                MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
                InputStream input = this.getApplication().getAssets().open("server.bks");
                options.setSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory(input, "123123"));

                IMqttToken token = mqttAndroidClient.connect(options); 
                token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
....
```

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory(InputStream keyStore, String password) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException {
        KeyStore ts;
        ts = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        ts.load(keyStore, password.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(ts);
        TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(null, tm, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }
....
```

Occured message on broker is

`1564452813: OpenSSL Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown`

I don't know what it mean

please help me the masters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

the cause were not code and keys.

in my bundle dependencies part :

```
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.1'
```

were the cause.

error is not occued below the mqttv3:1.2.1 version.

i don't know the difference both version.

Answer (score 0):

> mosquitto_pub -h ~~ -p ~~ -t ~~ -m ~~ --cafile ~~/ca.crt.pem
> --> it not works. i don't know why it doesn't work.

it does not work because you have mosquito.conf

**require_certificate true**

for use mosquitto_pub only with --cafile ca.cert you should change to

**require_certificate false**